# How to Create a Hard Black and White Shader with Inverted Edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, freestyle, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I am trying to recreate the art style below in Blender. I am able to get the hard black and white effect using a very powerful point light but I cannot figure out the edge effect. This effect can be clearly seen on the ground in front of the forbidden Dorito where the cracks transition from black when illuminated to white when in shade.  I am at a huge loss on how to achieve this effect. I have tried using freestyle but I don't know if there is a way to force a transition from black to white depending on shading.

For more examples of this effect please visit the artist webpage for this project, including the otherworldly music video using this same style here: https://cargocollective.com/helenejeudy/LORN-ANVIL

[image: Lorn Anvil]

Comment: You can render FreeStyle as render pass, then use this information in compositor to alternate between the your render and inverted render.

Comment: This might help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZR5XIjBmho

Answer (score 1):

After researching further, I found a few people who were working to achieve the same look.  Using the Freestyle edges is the correct answer.  There seems to be a few ways to go about doing this in Freestyle.

Set Freestyle edge detection to crease angle of 180.
Create a black line that is about 6 pixels wide
Create a white line that is about 3 pixels wide

Alternatively, you can do both black and white lines as 3 pixels and then apply a 2 pixel 2D offset under geometry.

[Advanced Freestyle Linework Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LElPE7R7Ka0&list=LL&index=5)

[Black and White “Ink” like shading](https://blenderartists.org/t/black-and-white-ink-like-shading/1219336/2)